# Actualizar imagen de perfil con php, jquery, mysql

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

necesito una pequeña ayudita con mi código.
no quiere actualizar la imagen de perfil del usuario.

este es mi código index.php

```
<?php
//Incluir archivo de configuración de base de datos
include_once 'dbconfig.php';

//Obtener ID de usuario actual de la sesión
$userId = 1;

//Obtener datos de usuario de la base de datos
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $userId");
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

//Foto de perfil de usuario
$userPicture = !empty($row['picture'])?$row['picture']:'no-image.png';
$userPictureURL = 'uploads/images/'.$userPicture;
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Si se hace clic en el enlace de edición de imagen
    $(".editLink").on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#fileInput:hidden").trigger('click');
    });

    //En el archivo seleccionado para cargar
    $("#fileInput").on('change', function(){
        var image = $('#fileInput').val();
        var img_ex = /(.jpg|.jpeg|.png|.gif)$/i;

        //validar tipo de archivo
        if(!img_ex.exec(image)){
            alert('Please upload only .jpg/.jpeg/.png/.gif file.');
            $('#fileInput').val('');
            return false;
        }else{
            $('.uploadProcess').show();
            $('#uploadForm').hide();
            $( "#picUploadForm" ).submit();
        }
    });
});

//Después de completar el proceso de carga de imágenes
function completeUpload(success, fileName) {
    if(success == 1){
        $('#imagePreview').attr("src", "");
        $('#imagePreview').attr("src", fileName);
        $('#fileInput').attr("value", fileName);
        $('.uploadProcess').hide();
    }else{
        $('.uploadProcess').hide();
        alert('¡Hubo un error durante la carga del archivo!');
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="user-box">
        <div class="img-relative">
            <!-- Cargando imagen -->
            <div class="overlay uploadProcess" style="display: none;">
                <div class="overlay-content"><img src="images/loading.gif"/></div>
            </div>
            <!-- Formulario de carga oculto -->
            <form method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="picUploadForm" target="uploadTarget">
                <input type="file" name="picture" id="fileInput"  style="display:none"/>
            </form>
            <iframe id="uploadTarget" name="uploadTarget" src="#" style="width:0;height:0;border:0px solid #fff;"></iframe>
            <!-- Enlace de actualización de imagen -->
            <a class="editLink" href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="images/edit.png"/></a>
            <!-- Imagen de perfil -->
            <img src="<?php echo $userPictureURL; ?>" id="imagePreview">
        </div>
        <div class="name">
            <h4><?php echo $row['name']; ?></h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Y este es el archivo en php que carga la imagen se llama: upload.php

```
<?php
if(!empty($_FILES['picture']['name'])){
    //Incluir archivo de configuración de base de datos
    include_once 'dbconfig.php';

    //Configuración de carga de archivos
    $result = 0;
    $uploadDir = "uploads/images/";
    $fileName = time().'_'.basename($_FILES['picture']['name']);
    $targetPath = $uploadDir. $fileName;

    //Subir archivo al servidor
    if(@move_uploaded_file($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'], $targetPath)){
        //Obtener ID de usuario actual de la sesión
        $userId = 1;

        //Actualizar el nombre de la imagen en la base de datos
        $update = $db->query("UPDATE users SET picture = '".$fileName."' WHERE id = $userId");

        //Update status
        if($update){
            $result = 1;
        }
    }

    //Función de carga de JavaScript para mostrar el estado de carga
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.top.window.completeUpload(' . $result . ','' . $targetPath . '');</script>  ';
}
?>
```

Estoy usando jquery para que cargue la foto automáticamente sin actualizar la pantalla, pero al momento se cargar la foto no hace nada se queda el boton cargando siempre.

Las imagenes de los usuarios se guardan solo con el nombre de la foto, y el archivo de la foto queda guardado en una carpeta que se llama images.

Quedo atento y muchas gracias de antemano.

Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deberías usar AJAX.

AJAX te ayudará ha realizar acciones al servidor sin recargar la página. Por ejemplo Subir una imagen nueva del perfil, almacenarla, recuperar la nueva imagen y mostrarla.

Resumiendo...

- Cuando haces click en cambiar imagen:
- Generas el código que necesites con JQuery.
- Llamas a AJAX que ejecute el archivo `upload.php`
- El archivo `upload.php`:
  Aquí almacenas, guardas, buscas o lo que necesites hacer con la BBDD
  y devuelves la imagen nueva.
- De nuevo en el JQuery con `success` colocas la imagen en la parte del front que te interese.

---

**Ejemplo**

Un ejemplo sencillo (simulado sin testar)

Solamente para ilustrar la explicación de arriba, deberás adaptarlo a tu código y tus necesidades...

```
$("#fileInput").on('change', function(){ 
     // Código x para subir y guardar imagen
   $.ajax({
       url: 'https://path/hacia/upload.php',
       success: function(respuesta) {
        // si todo esta ok mostramos la nueva imagen.
        $('#div_imagen').html(respuesta);
    },
    error: function() {
        console.log("No se ha podido obtener la información");
    }
 });
});
```

El archivo upload.php donde se obtiene la imagen deberá devolver la imagen.

Ejemplo:

```
<?php
  // Obtienes la imagen desde donde este ...
  // Devuelves el resultado de la imagen...
  echo "<img src='el/PATH/de/la/Imagen' />";
?>
```

---

**Más información sobre AJAX**

https://openclassrooms.com/en/courses/4309491-simplifica-tus-proyectos-con-jquery/4981961-el-metodo-ajax

http://mialtoweb.es/uso-basico-de-ajax/

---

**Ejemplo sencillo de AJAX**

Un ejemplo sencillo para ilustrar el funcionamiento básico de AJAX y conocer su potencial.

**index.html**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#accion").on('click', function(){
           $.ajax({
               url: 'accion.php',
               success: function(respuesta) {
                $('#div-respuesta').html(respuesta);
            },
            error: function() {
                $('#div-respuesta').html("Ha ocurrido un error");
            }
         });
        });

});
</script>
<div id="accion">Pulsa para ver AJAX en Acción</div>
<div id="div-respuesta">Sin nada</div>
```

**accion.php**

```
<?php
echo "Esto es la respuesta";
?>
```

Comment: Buenos días hola Eduard, eso lo entiendo perfectamente.

Comment: El problema es que al hacer el update en el archivo upload.php no funciona, se queda cargando y no hace nada.

Comment: Has probado con `$.ajax` ?

Comment: No lo he probado con ajax no se ocmo usarlo debo leer más sobre ajax y ver como puedo hacerlo.

Comment: He puesto un `ejemplo sencillo de AJAX` para que puedas ver la mecánica y comprendas su funcionamiento y poderlo aplicar en tu caso.